# Spring Advice object [null] using JdkDynamicAopProxy

Tags: java, spring

Using an injected spring service service.listAll() i have the exception below :

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.UnknownAdviceTypeException: 
Advice object [null] is neither a supported subinterface of 
[org.aopalliance.aop.Advice] nor an [org.springframework.aop.Advisor]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.DefaultAdvisorAdapterRegistry.getInterceptors(DefaultAdvisorAdapterRegistry.java:88)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.DefaultAdvisorChainFactory.getInterceptorsAndDynamicInterceptionAdvice(DefaultAdvisorChainFactory.java:61)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.AdvisedSupport.getInterceptorsAndDynamicInterceptionAdvice(AdvisedSupport.java:482)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:188)
```

The Configuration Class

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @PropertySource("classpath:system/db.properties")
    @ComponentScan("com.agitech.agitech.service")
    public class ContextConfig {            
        protected static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ContextConfig.class);
        @Resource
        private Environment env;
        public void setEnv(Environment env) {
            this.env = env;
        }   
        private final Properties hibProperties() {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put( HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(HIBERNATE_DIALECT) );
            properties.put( HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL) );
            properties.put( "hibernate.bytecode.provider", "javassist" );
            properties.put( "hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister", false );     
            return properties;
        }   
        @Bean(name ="dataSource")
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            return dataSource( env.getRequiredProperty(DATABASE_URL) );
        }
        @Bean(name ="mgrJPA")
        public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
            JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
            transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
            return transactionManager;
        }
        public DataSource dataSource(String url) {              
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();     
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(DATABASE_DRIVER));
            dataSource.setUrl(url);
            dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(DATABASE_USERNAME));
            dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(DATABASE_PASSWORD));             

            return dataSource;
        }

        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
                        DataSource dataSource, String unitName, String... packages) {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = 
                                new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource( dataSource );        
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass( HibernatePersistence.class );
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan( packages );
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties( hibProperties() );
            entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName( unitName );
            return entityManagerFactoryBean;
        }

        @Bean(name ="mgrEMF")   
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
            return entityManagerFactory(dataSource(), "mgrUnit", Contract.class.getPackage().getName());        
        }   


    }
```

Comment: Please post relevant code and configuration.

Comment: ok i add the configuration, and the code is just the call of the listAll procedure of Service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i didn't annotade the listAll procedure of the Service with the @Transactional annotation, but i thought that given that its just select query i dont need a transaction

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are missing `<context:annotation-config/>` in your Spring configuration file therefore interceptor doesn't get injected into PointcutAdvisor