# Should we open transaction for a simple select queries?

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate

After solving this problem [Spring Advice object [null] using JdkDynamicAopProxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450672/spring-advice-object-null-using-jdkdynamicaopproxy?noredirect=1#comment35948443_23450672)
i am asking my self what is the purpose to open transaction for a simple select query ?!

Comment: Did you log the actual request on the SQL server side? Probably there was more than a single query as a result of your `listAll()` call.

Comment: One reason is locking: you lock data and prevent them from changing, e.g. select ... from ... for update nowait in Oracke

Comment: yes it return probably a list of records and what this change?

Comment: No it a just one select query

Comment: So could you confirm me that the transaction is not required if we have a simple Select, that's what i want to confirm, because i have another project with witch i dont use transaction for select queries and i never have problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If its a very simple SELECT query then there is no need to open and commit the transaction. As its just read only data.

Example

```
public long findOrderItemCount() {
    Session session = getSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("select count(*) from OrderItem ");
    long count = (long)query.list().get(0);
    session.close();
    return count;
}
```

Comment: OK its confirm what i thought before, so the exception that i had is probably do to something else thank you